# How to add details on an image?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="cook.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cook.css">

<details>
  <summary>TEST</summary>
  <p> - bknf;nvdnvdnvldnvldvldbvldvbldvbldvvvbkh.</p>
</details>

<img src="oasis-and-car.png">
<details>
  <summary>TEST</summary>
  <p> - bknf;nvdnvdnvldnvldvldbvldvbldvbldvvvbkh.</p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>TEST</summary>
  <p>thestttttttt</p>
</details>
```

I want to add an image with some bullets next to it like the some descriptions and when you click on the bullets it shows you the info, like [this](https://isunenergy.com/en/oasis/introducing-oasis?settings=2%2C2) site where it has the solar panel and when you click on the plus sign it gives you the information. Mine is working, the only problem is they are not in the right place i want them to be in sides. Also is there any plugin in Wordpress for this?

Comment: Use position absolute to place them anywhere yoiu want

Comment: @Ibu thank you for giving ur time to answer my question, can you give me an example please i do not know alot of coding .Do you know any plugin that i can find for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use absolute position. Here's an example.

```css
.pos1{ 
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

.pos2{ 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="cook.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cook.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  
   <details class="pos1">
  <summary>TEST</summary>
  <p> - bknf;nvdnvdnvldnvldvldbvldvbldvbldvvvbkh.</p>
 </details>
  
  <img src="oasis-and-car.png" >
  <details class="pos2">
  <summary>TEST</summary>
  <p> - bknf;nvdnvdnvldnvldvldbvldvbldvbldvvvbkh.</p>
 </details>
  
  
   <details>
  <summary>TEST</summary>
<p>thestttttttt</p>
 </details>
  
  
  
  

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You Itay Gal it makes more sense  ,Do you think i can find a plugin for it or do u know any?

Comment: I'm not familiar with such plugin but I don't think you need a plugin when the solution is 3 css lines..

Comment: bcz im using a wordpress theme and idk where to put them ,also im not sure if this thing will be responsive

Comment: Yes, it's responsive - the `top`,`left`,`bottom`,`right` are actually relative to the parent. Just resize your browser to test it

Comment: last question bro so if i want to add more classes i only need to change the numbers right ?

Comment: correct, the position needs to be set to `absolute` and the values of `top` etc will determined where your element will be positioned relative to the parent